# Try - Catch CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I am trying to implement try - catch in CSOM - JavaScript, I have the following code:

```
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var exScope= new SP.ExceptionHandlingScope(ctx);
        var s= exScope.startScope();

        //try
        var t= exScope.startTry();

        var contactsList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(_title);
        ctx.load(contactsList);
        contactsList.set_description("My Contacts List");
        contactsList.update();

        t.dispose();

        //catch
        var c = exScope.startCatch();

        var listCI = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        listCI.set_title("Contacts List");
        listCI.set_description("My Contacts List");
        listCI.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.contacts);
        listCI.set_quickLaunchOption(SP.QuickLaunchOptions.on);
        ctx.get_web().get_lists().add(listCI);
        c.dispose();

        //finally
        var f= exScope.startFinally();
        f.dispose();

        s.dispose();
        //Execute
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(onEnsureSuccess, onEnsureFail);
```

I am defining exeption scope, and try scope to make sure the list exists, if it doesn't a catch will be thrown and it will create a list, so I am handling all errors on the server. What happens is i have an error in `onEnsureFail` that the list exists, should I get no error? Shouldn't the try block only be executed and the catch not be executed? I don't know what's going on with my code, any help?

Comment: What is the value of the _title variable and what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Hi Rob, the error message saying that there is a list already exists in that site and it can't create it, and my code goes to the onEnsureFail function.

Comment: What is the value of the _title variable?

Comment: Hi Rob, The title variable I am passing to the function is a string 'Contacts', which I want to be the title of the list.

Comment: In the catch block you are setting the title of the list to 'Contacts List'. So, you should expect to get an error if you have a list named 'Contacts List' but not one named 'Contacts'. SharePoint will try to load the list named 'Contacts' which will fail. Then it will fall into the catch block where it will try to create the list named 'Contacts List' which will also fail. SharePoint will then throw this second exception back from the service call.